# How to change react-router-native location on native-module callback

Tags: react-native, history, react-lifecycle, react-router-native

I'm building a react-native application that displays Service overlay (like those facebook messenger bubble heads), implement in Android only, and on the overlay click it should go  back to the app in a specific screen.

I'm using react-router-native and I have my routes structured like this:

App.js

```
<NativeRouter>
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
        <Main>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/home" component={Home} />
                <Route exact path="/progress" component={RouteProgress} />
                <Route exact path="/search" component={Search} />
            </Switch>            
        </Main>
    </ApolloProvider>
</NativeRouter>
```

The `Main` component has these:

Main.js

```
componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.props.location.pathname);
    if(this.props.location.pathname === '/') {
        this.props.history.push("/home");
    }       
}
```

The callback from my Native module is being called like this:

FloatingView.java

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        if (lastAction == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN || delta < 3) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(FloatingWindow.this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);

            FloatingViewPackage.callback.invoke();                                              

            stopSelf();
        }
```

The callback is defined in the component `Search`, which also executes the native module:

Search.js

```
<Button onPress={() => FloatingView.init(() => {
    console.log('go to progress 1');
    this.props.history.push("/progress");

    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('go to progress 2');
        this.props.history.push("/progress");
    }, 1000);
})}
```

The problem is that `this.props.history.push("/progress");` doesn't work neither outside the timeout nor inside. 
Outside the timeout, the function is called before `Main` `componentDidMount` but `location.pathname` is not updated. Inside it the function is called after, but it doesn't navigate to the right screen. It always fall into `/home`.

I thought this my be a life cycle issue, since the Search component is not mounted. I've been trying to figure a way out to make this work. I tried using the `Redirect` component:

```
<Button onPress={() => FloatingView.init(() => <Redirect to="/progress" />)}
```

Does anyway can think of a way around this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution, don't know if the best one, but it works.

Created a singleton `navigation.js`

navigation.js

```
export default {
    entryPoint: '/home'
};
```

And changed the following files:

Search.js

```
<Button onPress={() => FloatingView.init(() => {
   navigation.entryPoint = "/progress";
})}
```

Main.js

```
componentDidMount() {
    if(this.props.location.pathname === '/') {
        this.props.history.push(navigation.entryPoint);
    }       
}
```